# Python (2.7) Queue Duplicates

Tags: python, queue, duplicates

I am trying to create a queue that contains url strings for a simple web crawler.  I don't want duplicate items to be added to a queue, so I have created a helper function to check the url to be added to the queue and see if it is already in it.  I was trying to use this code (which I modified from a similar stackoverflow question), pages is the queue:

```
def is_in_url_list(self, url):
    return url in self.pages.queue
```

However, I cannot seem to get this to work.  Even when I pass something that should return true, it returns false.  Is there a better way to go about this?  Thanks!

Comment: What type is the queue you are talking about?

Comment: I am using the queue module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), so I am assuming it is a standard FIFO queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purposes, there's no point in using `queue`, instead you can just use the normal `list` with [`list.popleft()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues) or you can use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque). In case you're curious, the `queue` is used for multiprocessing, since it provides a thread-safe data-structure that different threads can communicate using (if this sounds like gibberish to you, just ignore it)

Since the problem you describe is a common one, the links I've provided actually show how one can use lists as both stacks and queues.

Now, `deque` is a double ended queue, hence the `d`. This can pop from both ends, becoming a stack when need be, and a queue when necessary.

Now you might be wondering, well if `deque` and `list` can achieve the same results, why use one over the other, and this too is explained within the documentation:

> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for
>   fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for
>   pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and
>   position of the underlying data representation.

Now the choice is yours.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!  I am fairly new to python and I didn't realize that a deque was the correct choice.  It works perfectly now.